# Deleting item from ListView using custom ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object>{
...
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        ...
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (...) {
                    MyListAdapter.this.remove(); //what parameter to pass?
                    MyListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    MyListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Error deleting item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
         ...
         ...
```

I'm creating custom `ArrayAdapter`, there is a button in the listview item layout, When clicked I want to delete the listview item from the listview. I'm not sure i'm doing it right..

Any help will be appriciated, thanks.

Comment: position of the item

Comment: Do you just want to remove it from the list or do you also want to remove it from the 'backing array for your list ? If so, what sort of array do you use to get data into the ListView ?

Comment: first get the position of item, then delete it from array, finally `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

I did similar coding before. There are 2 ways to do this. Sample code from yours:

1)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   if (...) {
      this.remove(<object>);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: object should be relative to the item in `position`, used in getView().

2)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (...) {
       <object>.remove(position);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: object is the container like an ArrayList, Hashmap, used in getView().

I think calling notifyDataSetInvalidated is not necessary, taking computer time.